# Is there a way we can use comparison operator with complex and real numbers?

Tags: c++

I want to compare determinant, but i write it like this it gets error and is not executing. How can I compare complex no with real no for using if else condition.
I am using that if condition because I want that if roots are real then answer will not be in imaginary form like x+0i or (x,0). I simply want answer to be x.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    complex <double> a,b,c;
    complex <double> x1,x2;
    cout<<setprecision(3);
    cout<<"Coefficient of square term: "; cin>>a;
    cout<<"Coefficient of linear term: "; cin>>b;
    cout<<"Coefficient of constant term: "; cin>>c;
    complex <double> det=(b*b)-(4.0*a*c);

    if (det>=0.0)
    {
        x1=(-b+sqrt(det))/(2.0*a);
        x2=(-b-sqrt(det))/(2.0*a);
        cout<<x1<<" "<<x2;
    }
    else
    {
        x1=(-b+sqrt(det))/(2.0*a);
        x2=(-b-sqrt(det))/(2.0*a);
        cout<<showpos;
        cout<<x1.real()<<x1.imag()<<"i \n"<<x2.real()<<x2.imag()<<"i";
    } 
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) doesn't have any overloaded relative comparison operators, but there's nothing stopping you from implementing them if you can clearly define their meaning.

Comment: It's not mathematically meaningful to order complex numbers. That's why you can't use >= on a complex number. What do you think this code should do `det>=0.0`? How would you define whether a complex number is greater than zero or not?

Comment: You can not compare two complex numbers (at least, you check if two complex numbers are equal iff their real and complex parts are the same). You can compare their modulus, which resort to compare two real numbers.

Comment: Also if you look at the two branches of your if statement they use exactly the same formulae. So it's not really clear why you even need an if statement.

Comment: You need to use the second branch of the if statement if sqrt(det) has a non-0 complex term or us purely real and less than 0.

Comment: This looks like a math problem. `std::sqrt(std::complex z)` exists, and it returns a result for any `z`. So there's no point in checking `det` as you would do for real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed, it's questionable whether you really want to have an operator to do this. The operator compares modulae, and it will probably be clearer in the code to do that explicitly.

However, operators can be overridden as top level functions, do if you really want to, here' the code:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator >= (const complex<T>& l, const T& r)
{
    return (l.imag() * l.imag() + l.real() * l.real()) >= r * r;

}
```

Though of course here you're doing a comparison with zero, and the modulus can never be negative, so I think your logic may be at fault somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a math misunderstanding, I guess.

The standard quadratic equation would have real coefficients `a, b, c`. Then `det` is also real and it can easily be checked for `det >= 0`. Which you have to do if you want to restrict to *real* solutions. But you don't have to check if you use *complex* `x1, x2`, because the complex numbers will handle `sqrt(-1)` automatically.

If you really want to have complex `a, b, c`, the formulae are also fine. There is no mathematical meaning in `det >= 0` for complex `det`. The only interesting case you might want to check is `det == 0` resulting in `x1` and `x2` being equal.

Aha, now I finally get what you want to check. **Case one is for real solutions!** To get that right, you have to check that `det` **is real and not negative**. I would write this as

```
if ( ( det - conj(det) == 0.0 ) && ( real(det) >= 0.0 ) ) { ... }
```

Note that you have to write `0.0` to clarify that it is a `double`. Also note that the simpler `imag(det) == 0.0` for checking if it is real might run into 'the usual' problems with comparing floating point numbers directly.

Comment: I am using that if condition because I want that if roots are real then answer will not be in imaginary form like x+0i or (x,0). i simply want answer to be x.

Comment: That's what I thought and said above. Even in bold. The condition is NOT 'det >= 0', but rather 'det is real and non-negative'

Answer (score 0):

```
// Read about the complex number comparison 
// how on earth you can compare imaginary number with a real number
if (det.real() >= 0)
{
    x1 = (-b+sqrt(det))/(2.0*a);
    x2 = (-b-sqrt(det))/(2.0*a);
    cout<<x1<<" "<<x2;
}
```

A complex number is a combination of both real and imaginary numbers, how can you compare a complex number with an imaginary number?

If you want to compare, then you need to compare the real part with real part and complex with complex.

Comment: you can compare two imaginary numbers, there is just not one generally useful or accepted way. For example comparing their magnitude can be used to define a `<` relation, but that relation has limited use

Comment: I agree with you most of the time we do this but when we are faced with a situation where real parts are equal we go for lexicographic order and check the imaginary parts.

Comment: I am using that if condition because I want that if roots are real then answer will not be in imaginary form like x+0i or (x,0). i simply want answer to be x.